# PHP вычесть час из даты

Tags: php

Я получаю дату в виде строчки: "09.03.2017 18:46". Как мне из нее вычесть час, чтобы получить такую строчку "09.03.2017 17:46"?

Comment: Напишите код по которому вы получаете дату, мы не можем подсказать нужное решение без полноты информации.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров, почему? Дата явно может быть исключительно в переменной.

Comment: Какой смысл от того, что пишут люди ниже, если человек не может решить такую простую проблему - то ее нужно расписать. Может у него в unix дата выводится, а потом в формат передается, есть смысл отнять час от туда и сократить код. Вот почему всегда нужно код прикладывать свой, а не "напишите за меня", это не благотворительный фонд "умелые ручки". :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Само время я получаю через  <input type="datetime-local">,  при нажатии submit возвращается значение этого input....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть простой вариант:

```
$date = date_create("09.03.2017 18:46");
date_modify($date, "-1 hour"); // на 1 час назад
$date_new = date_format($date, "d.m.Y H:i");
echo $date_new; // 09.03.2017 17:46
```

Переменная `$date_new` - новая дата.

Answer (score 3):

Например вот так:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('09.03.2017 18:46') - 60*60;
$date = date('d.m.y H:i', $timestamp);

echo $date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php) и в частности его методом [date_sub](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php), который вычтет любой [интервал](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php) в зависимости от переданного [шаблона](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props)

```
$input = '09.03.2017 18:46';

$output = new DateTime($input);
$output->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $output->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно завести привычку работать с датой/временем, как с датой и временем.
Иначе придётся учитывать кучу тонкостей.

Функция для вычитания интервала из даты: [DateTime::sub](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('09.03.2017 18:46');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/A5Z9S)

Answer (score 0):

//всё делается в одну строку

```
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('-1 hour'));
```

Comment: Здесь ты вычитаешь час от текущего времени. В общем случае дата может быть любой.