# Как сделать изменение месяца и года динамически на php?

Tags: php

Для построения графика мне необходимо по Х выстроить месяца с годами. На примере `<?php echo date( "m.20y" );?>`. Соответственно по месяцам я могу сделать +1, а и то не знаю вдруг покажет 13 и так далее, а как быть с годами, что-бы в соответствии месяца менялся год. 
Распределение такое `12.2017   01.2018   02.2018` и так далее. Вручную постоянно менять данные не ахти, может есть такое решение выводить месяца будущие в правильном виде? Значения вставляются каждое отдельно! Вот пример кода с датами

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['2017-12','2018-01','2018-02', '2018-03','2018-04','2018-05','2018-06','2018-07','2018-08','2018-09','2018-10','2018-11']
 },
     yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: '1 человек, в одну сторону'
        }
     },
     series: [{
        name: 'Москва-Адлер',<? echo ['1 человек, в одну сторону']?>,
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, <? echo $AER['data']['2017-12']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-01']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-02']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-03']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-04']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-05']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-06']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-07']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-08']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-02']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-09']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-10']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-11']['price']; ?>]
     },
```

Comment: .....а зачем +1?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Я знаю что не зачем, я не знаю как по другому.

Comment: выбирайте любой пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637416/191482 | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754783/191482 | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727885/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы можете на примере показать как это сделать. Вот та часть кода отвечающая за даты (пример в вопросе (дополнил))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = [];
$startMonth = 12;
$startYear=2017;
$monthesOnAxis=13;
for($i = 0; $i < $monthesOnAxis; $i++){
    $dates[] = date('Y-m', mktime(
        0, 0, 0, $startMonth + $i, 1, $startYear
    ));
}
```

После этого у нас в `$dates` будут все нужные "засечки" месяцев. Функция `mktime()` нормально работает с "неправильными" датами, для неё 13.2017 == 01.2018

Предполагаю, что ваш код это JS, тогда вывести даты в него из php можно, например, так:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: <?=json_encode($dates)?>
 },
 ...
```

**UPD:** для поля `data` код такой (стоять должен ниже, чем код, формирующий `$dates`):

```
$data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; //нули вначале как в вашем примере.
foreach($dates as $date){
    $data[] = $AER['data'][$date]['price'];
}
```

Выводим в js точно также:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Москва-Адлер',<? echo ['1 человек, в одну сторону']?>,
        data: <?=json_encode($data)?>
     }, ...
```

Comment: Для categories все отлично работает спасибо вам огромное. А как для data сделать data?

Comment: Вот для этого как подставить эту переменную? <? echo $AER['data']['2017-12']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-01']['price']; ?>,<? echo $AER['data']['2018-02']['price']; ?>

Comment: Заранее огромное спасибо, с уважением

Comment: @Arcadiy, обновил ответ

Comment: С data график исчезает http://aviaciya.com/slide/test.php

Comment: Вижу, что в коде вместо значений проставлены null. Странно, по идее, если, например, в $date у нас '2017-12', то записи $AER['data']['2017-12']['price'] и $AER['data'][$date]['price'] идентичны. Надо смотреть, почему массив $data неверно заполняется.
Вы можете на вашей странице вначале написать сделать var_dump($AER['data'])?

Comment: Дмитрий я не знаю куда написать. Вот код страницы https://cloud.mail.ru/home/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20(3)%20(1).txt

Comment: Неверная ссылка, 404-ю даёт

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DZvA/5q6sjvCRf

Comment: Ясно, проблема в том, что переменная $AER у вас создается в строчке 45, а код, заполняющий $data находится На строках 22-25. $AER должна быть задана до этого момента. Надо поставить код c `foreach($dates as $date){...` после кода `$AER=json_decode($response,true);`

Comment: Поставил график есть, но появились 13 14 15 16 и 17 месяца http://aviaciya.com/slide/test.php

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70659/discussion-between-dmitry-and-arcadiy).